# Как поместить контейнеры в другой контейнер?(Python3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qlayout, qvboxlayout

Я учусь делать приложения на `Python3` с помощью модуля `PyQt5`. Решил, что будет здорово хранить виджеты внутри контейнеров - **QHBoxLayout** и **QVBoxLayout**(других я не знаю).

Но, как я понял, в таких контейнерах виджеты не могут располагаться вертикально и горизонтально одновременно, а я не планировал, что абсолютно все виджеты в окне будут выстроены только в ряд или только в столбик.

Тогда подумал, что можно добавлять контейнеры с виджетами в один общий контейнер.

**Пожалуйста, подскажите, как правильно сделать то, что я описал**?

Нарисовал картинку, чтобы было лучше понятно о чем говорю:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пытался добиться такого результата двумя способами, но оба привели к ошибкам.

**1 способ:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка1")
button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка2")
button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка3")
button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка4")

box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

box2.addWidget(button1)
box2.addWidget(button2)

box3.addWidget(button3)
box3.addWidget(button4)

box1.setLayout(box2)
box1.setLayout(box3)
window.setLayout(box1)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Ошибка:**

> AttributeError: 'QHBoxLayout' object has no attribute 'setLayout'

**2 способ:**

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка1")
button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка2")
button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка3")
button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка4")

box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

box2.addWidget(button1)
box2.addWidget(button2)

box3.addWidget(button3)
box3.addWidget(button4)

box1.addWidget(box2)
box1.addWidget(box3)
window.setLayout(box1)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**Ошибка:**

> TypeError: addWidget(self, QWidget, stretch: int = 0, alignment: Union[Qt.Alignment, Qt.AlignmentFlag] = Qt.Alignment()): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QVBoxLayout'

Comment: Для лейаутов надо использовать `addLayout`

Comment: А, вообще, рекомендую QtCreator, используя его, вы быстрее научитесь

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо было сделать еще одну попытку.

> QBoxLayout::addLayout(QLayout *layout, int stretch = 0)
>
> Добавляет layout  в конец box с коэффициентом растяжения.

Но во многих случаях вам очень пригодится `QGridLayout` и `QFormLayout`

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtWidgets.QWidget()

button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка1")
button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка2")
button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка3")
button4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Кнопка4")

box1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
box2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
box3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()

box2.addWidget(button1)
box2.addWidget(button2)

box3.addWidget(button3)
box3.addWidget(button4)

#box1.setLayout(box2)
box1.addLayout(box2)            # <<<
box1.addLayout(box3)            # <<<
window.setLayout(box1)

window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Правильно сделать используя `QGridLayout`, который как раз позволяет делать табличную разметку.

[Пример](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qgridlayout_class.htm).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо! Но, кнопки - это просто пример. Я планировал добавлять и другие виджеты. Я правильно понимаю, что с QGridLayout это невозможно? В любом случае, спасибо, буду знать:)

Comment: @MAXIM045 `QGridLayout` - это самый универсальный `QLayout`, используя его - все возможно.